# Angular - Importing modified list of modules

Tags: angular

I have a file that exports ParentModule and an array of it's imported modules

```
export const PARENT_MODULES = [
    module1,
    ...
    someModule,
    ...
    moduleN
];

@NgModule({ imports: [...PARENT_MODULES] })
export class ParentModule{ }
```

I would like create `ModifiedParentModule` that is the same as `ParentModule` except one import (`anotherModule` instead of `someModule`). Is there any way to do it without typing the whole import list again?

I tried this:

```
export const replaceModules = module => 
    module.name === someModule.name ? anotherModule.name : module;

export const MODIFIED_PARENT_MODULES = PARENT_MODULES.map(replaceModules)

@NgModule({ imports: [...MODIFIED_PARENT_MODULES ]})
export class ModifiedParentModule{ }
```

but it gives error

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'providers' in null
at C:\app-ext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:111:73
at Array.filter (native)
at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:111:29)
at includeLazyRouteAndSubRoutes (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:66:25)
at Array.reduce (native)
at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:54:36)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\app-ext\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a BaseSharedParentModule that exports all of your required shared modules

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [...PARENT_MODULES],
exports: [...PARENT_MODULES]

 })
export class BaseSharedParentModule { }
```

The in both of the ParentModule and ModiefiedParentModule import the container module as shown below

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [BaseSharedParentModule],
 })
export class ParentModule{ }



@NgModule({ 
imports: [BaseSharedParentModule],
 })
export class ModifiedParentModule{ }
```